# are new weights generated for each iteration/run in tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensorboard

```
def trainx(x):
    train = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(x).minimize(error)
    return train

with tf.Session() as sess:
    for i in [0.01,0.02,0.03, 0.04]: #
        merge = tf.summary.merge_all()
        tf.global_variables_initializer().run()



        writter = tf.summary.FileWriter('4004/'+str(i), sess.graph)

        for i1 in range(100):

            error_sum = sess.run(merge, {x:inp, y:out})
            writter.add_summary(error_sum, i1)
            sess.run(trainx(i), {x:inp, y:out})
```

just passing you part of the code, to make things more simple.
Please look at the picture bellow:

[image]

If you see red line starts at about 0.370 and blue at about 0.310. Does this mean, initial weight is not the same for all runs in tensorflow? Because if it would be, all lines would start from same point, considering Gradient decent is applied after error/loss function. I think for each iteration, new weights are generated and this is not I am looking for. How could I fix this? would appreciate it.

Comment: What are the different lines representing?

Comment: @Engineero oh, it's loss/error function for one layer network... nothing special.

Comment: The `trainx(i)` inside the loop will create a new `tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer` (with *linearly increasing learning rate*) in each iteration. This is unlikely to give the intended result. Instead, create an optimizer and call `minimize()` once outside the loop, and reuse that training operation inside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the default initializer for the weights is random. You can make it better by setting the random seed. https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/set_random_seed

```
tf.set_random_seed(666)
```